# How to display a float on the Pebble

Tags: c, pebble-sdk

I am building an app that displays how many miles you have gone and I want it to have 3 decimal places. So "0.435 miles" for instance. I have tried the code below:

```
static char stopwatch_miles[50];
snprintf(stopwatch_miles, sizeof(stopwatch_miles), "%.3f miles", num_miles);
text_layer_set_text(miles_layer, stopwatch_miles);
```

`num_miles` is a calculated floating point variable. However, Pebble deprecated using floats in `snprintf` in 1.13. Is there an easy workaround? Maybe using an `int`, multiplying it by 1000 before my math and adding the decimal places in formatting?

Answer (score 4):

You could try multiply 'num_miles' by 1000, convert it to an integer, and them display as a regular int value

```
snprintf(stopwatch_miles, sizeof(int), "%d.%d miles", (int)num_miles, (int)(num_miles*1000)%1000);
```

---

**EDIT**: Manül gently reminded me that the second %d should be %03d instead of the former answer. The line should then be:

```
    snprintf(stopwatch_miles, sizeof(stopwatch_miles), "%d.%03d miles", (int)num_miles, (int)(num_miles*1000)%1000);
```

Comment: the second %d should be %03d to handle for example 0.043 miles

Comment: I could not get this to function properly. What I got to work is doing the exact same thing in a different function, using 2 ints, one for before period, and one for after, and doing the whole thing as an int instead of a float. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` is wrong here. It needs to be the size of `stopwatch_miles`

Comment: @JaretBurkett, that is exactly what the code above is supposed to do.